# Message inside .csproj file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using Visual Studio 2017. **Where and how** may I see the following message included in .csproj file?

```
<Target Name="LogMessage">
    <Message Importance="High" Text="Hello world!" />
</Target>
```

Moreover, when the .csproj file is running? `Is it only when we open the project or every time we build the project?`

Comment: What do you mean with _.csproj file is running_ ? This is a data file that describes the configuration of your source files to be compiled by Visual Studio. There is no _run of_ a .csproj file

Comment: Every time you build project .csproj is interpreted by MSBuild, therefore we can consider that ".csproj is running with every build".